# Is it possible to evaluate the integral $\int_D\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2}$ on a disk of radius $R$ by using geometry or symmetry?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

Is it possible to evaluate the integral $\int_D\sqrt{R^2 - x^2 - y^2}$ on a disk of radius $R$ by using geometry or symmetry?

The question is a bit vague, but this is what is asked.

I have come up with a solution by going to polar coordinates. However I think the aim is to avoid this coordinate transformation.

Maybe we can use pythagoras at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is the volume of the hemisphere described, of radius $R$

With $z \geq 0,$ take $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2,$ what do you get by solving for $z?$